# RIGHT JOIN 3 tables to 1 left table, and joining a column from 2 other tables to the right side

Tags: mysql

I'm creating a social network and I have a pretty specific case, and I've almost got the correct query. I have 6 tables that I'm merging into one query.
Table `recent` is used to find the exact rows on tables `brostplain`, `egobrost`, and `brostpublic`, it gets complicated when also finding a match on `members` and `egos` tables, where members.username will be matched to `brostplain` and `brostpublic` on column id, and egos.egoname will be matched to `egobrost` on column `egoid`. All of it is sorted by unix timestamp, in the recent.realtime column. Here's the current query:

```
   SELECT recent.id, 
          recent.brosttype, 
          recent.postid, 
          recent.realtime, 
          members.username,
          egos.egoname, 
          brostplain.id, 
          brostplain.postid, 
          brostplain.content, 
          brostplain.up, 
          brostplain.down, 
          brostplain.timedata, 
          brostplain.realtime, 
          brostplain.attached, 
          brostplain.replies, 
          brostplain.ext, 
          brostplain.onpage, 
          brostplain.touser, 
          brostplain.isego, 
          brostplain.category, 
          egobrost.egoid, 
          egobrost.postid, 
          egobrost.content, 
          egobrost.up, 
          egobrost.down, 
          egobrost.timedata, 
          egobrost.realtime, 
          egobrost.attached, 
          egobrost.replies, 
          egobrost.ext, 
          egobrost.onpage, 
          egobrost.touser, 
          egobrost.isego, 
          egobrost.category, 
          brostpublic.id, 
          brostpublic.postid, 
          brostpublic.content, 
          brostpublic.up, 
          brostpublic.down, 
          brostpublic.timedata, 
          brostpublic.realtime, 
          brostpublic.attached, 
          brostpublic.replies, 
          brostpublic.ext, 
          brostpublic.category, 
          brostpublic.isego 
     FROM recent 
LEFT JOIN brostplain ON recent.brosttype=brostplain.brosttype 
      AND recent.postid=brostplain.postid 
LEFT JOIN brostpublic ON recent.brosttype=brostpublic.brosttype 
      AND recent.postid=brostpublic.postid 
LEFT JOIN egobrost ON recent.brosttype=egobrost.brosttype 
      AND recent.postid=egobrost.postid 
LEFT JOIN egos ON egos.egoid=egobrost.egoid
     JOIN members ON brostplain.id=members.id OR brostpublic.id=members.id 
    WHERE recent.id='2' ORDER BY recent.realtime DESC
```

Now this gets all the relevant rows, but it doesn't return any results for egobrost rows due to the way egos table is joined, and I can't figure out where to put the join or how to implement it. If I omit the JOIN on egos and remove egos.egoname from my SELECT, it will show the rows on egobrost table no problem, but I need the egoname for my output. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT (Solved): After much thought I solved this by adding LEFT to the JOIN on `members`. Now the result set is complete. Thanks to those who contributed.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand - this query returns the "relevant" rows but not the egobrost rows? How can you tell? Are there missing rows, or just NULL values being returned in rows that you would expect to have data?

Comment: I'm using phpMyAdmin to test my queries, the egobrost rows are missing entirely from results when I join the egos table.

Comment: I can't see any reason why the presence or absence of the LEFT JOIN to egos would remove rows from your resultset, especially because all the rowcount would appear to be determined by the tables recent, brostplain, brostpublic and members. Do you have any other way to test the query to ensure that it isn't the test tool that is introducing issues?

Comment: I am also testing the query in a PHP mysql_query on the server. The rows from tables brostplain, brostpublic, and egobrost are determined explicitly by matching brosttype and postid columns with `recent` table. the purpose of members and egos tables is only to get the name of the person who generated the post.

Comment: A left join should make no difference to the number of rows being returned. I am a little concerned that you are making references to "rows" being missing" rather than simply having NULL values.

Are you always receiving the same number of rows in your result set, regardless of whether the LEFT JOIN to egos is included or not?

Comment: There should be 1 more row returned from egobrost, (total 10) and only 9 (rows 0-8) are returned when left joining egos, leaving that one out. I'm almost considering querying it separately if I can't resolve it using this method, and rearranging the arrays, which would be troublesome, but I'm sure I could do it. 2 queries is still better than 10 anyway. But I would like to resolve this if I can. RIGHT JOIN egos obviously returns 0 rows, and JOIN egos (omitting LEFT) returns 0 rows as well.

Comment: My point is that egobrost is not responsible for "returning rows" - you are left joining to it from recent, so are just trying to get further data for your result row. egobrost will not "add" any rows to your result set, which is the source of my confusion.

Comment: Ah yeah same with my confusion as well, this is actually the first time I've posted on stackoverflow since most problems I've usually been able to solve on my own, this one has me stumped. mysql_error isn't being triggered because there's no errors in the query. You are correct, the expected behavior would be adding egoname column to the result set, however that column is null because it isn't matching any rows.

Comment: I thought it might have been because using LEFT JOIN would match it to the recent table, or if it's matching it to brostplain or brostpublic instead of the desired behavior, wasn't sure if it was the arrangement of the query causing this.

Comment: After much thought I solved this by adding LEFT to the JOIN on `members`. Now the result set is complete. Thanks for the help! How do I close this?

Comment: @DaveWilson Post your final query as an answer, and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved by changing the JOIN on members to a LEFT JOIN, coinciding with the LEFT JOIN on egos. Here is the final query:

```
SELECT recent.id, 
          recent.brosttype, 
          recent.postid, 
          recent.realtime, 
          members.username,
          egos.egoname, 
          brostplain.id, 
          brostplain.postid, 
          brostplain.content, 
          brostplain.up, 
          brostplain.down, 
          brostplain.timedata, 
          brostplain.realtime, 
          brostplain.attached, 
          brostplain.replies, 
          brostplain.ext, 
          brostplain.onpage, 
          brostplain.touser, 
          brostplain.isego, 
          brostplain.category, 
          egobrost.egoid, 
          egobrost.postid, 
          egobrost.content, 
          egobrost.up, 
          egobrost.down, 
          egobrost.timedata, 
          egobrost.realtime, 
          egobrost.attached, 
          egobrost.replies, 
          egobrost.ext, 
          egobrost.onpage, 
          egobrost.touser, 
          egobrost.isego, 
          egobrost.category, 
          brostpublic.id, 
          brostpublic.postid, 
          brostpublic.content, 
          brostpublic.up, 
          brostpublic.down, 
          brostpublic.timedata, 
          brostpublic.realtime, 
          brostpublic.attached, 
          brostpublic.replies, 
          brostpublic.ext, 
          brostpublic.category, 
          brostpublic.isego 
     FROM recent 
LEFT JOIN brostplain ON recent.brosttype=brostplain.brosttype 
      AND recent.postid=brostplain.postid 
LEFT JOIN brostpublic ON recent.brosttype=brostpublic.brosttype 
      AND recent.postid=brostpublic.postid 
LEFT JOIN egobrost ON recent.brosttype=egobrost.brosttype 
      AND recent.postid=egobrost.postid 
LEFT JOIN egos ON egos.egoid=egobrost.egoid
LEFT JOIN members ON brostplain.id=members.id OR brostpublic.id=members.id 
    WHERE recent.id='2' ORDER BY recent.realtime DESC
```